# HTMLでクリック時に展開するメニューで、下のコンテンツをずらしたくない

Tags: javascript, html

次のHTMLの「BBB」をクリックした時に、下に展開するメニューを出したいです。

AAA　BBB　CCC　DDD
　　 メニュー1(←展開されるメニュー)
　　 メニュー2(←展開されるメニュー)

ただ、普通に展開すると「ここにウェブページのコンテンツなどが書き込まれます。」がそのまま下にずれてしまいます。

やりたいのは、「ここにウェブページのコンテンツなどが書き込まれます。」の上にクリック時のメニューを展開したいです。(展開メニューの文字が乗っかって上書きされるようなイメージ)

可能でしょうか？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>トップページ</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">

    <div style="background-color : #b1c4e0">
        <br/>
        <span style="font-size:x-large">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            テスト 
        </span>
    </div>

    <table border="1" style="width:100%;background-color : #6068de">
      <tr >
        <td style="width:12%"><div style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff">AAA</div></td>
        <td style="width:12%">
            <div style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff">
                BBB
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:12%"><div style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff">CCC</div></td>
        <td style="width:12%"><div style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff">DDD</div></td>
        <td style="width:52%"><div style="text-align:right;color:#ffffff">EEE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div> 

ここにウェブページのコンテンツなどが書き込まれます。

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`position`スタイルの`absolute`もしくは`fixed`を使用することになると思います。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/position

> absolute
>
> 要素のためのスペースが確保されません。代わりに、その要素の位置を、位置指定された祖先要素のうちもっとも近いもの、もしくは、その要素の包含ブロックを基準にして決めます。絶対位置指定されたボックスのマージンは、他の要素のマージンと相殺されません。

簡単なスニペットを以下挿入します。「BBB」メニューをクリックするとその下にメニューが展開します。

```js
!function() {
  var menuElements = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
  
  [].forEach.call(menuElements, function(menuElement) {
    menuElement.onclick = function() {
      this.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0].className = "submenu";
    };
  });
}();
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}

.submenu.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="menu">
      <div>AAA</div>
    </td>
    <td class="menu">
      <div>BBB</div>
      <div class="submenu is-hidden">
        <p>メニュー1(←展開されるメニュー)</p>
        <p>メニュー2(←展開されるメニュー)</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="menu">
      <div>CCC</div>
    </td>
    <td class="menu">
      <div>DDD</div>
    </td>
    <td class="menu">
      <div>EEE</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>メニューの下のコンテンツ</p>
<p>メニューの下のコンテンツ</p>
<p>メニューの下のコンテンツ</p>
<p>メニューの下のコンテンツ</p>
<p>メニューの下のコンテンツ</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap を使うか、ソースを参考にカスタマイズされてはいかがでしょうか？
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns